# Azure DevOps deploy overview

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, devops

I am looking for some help to understand how to use Azure DevOps to deploy the application I am working on to a Windows VM.

Currently process: Our code is currently in Azure Git repo and we have two QA servers, the QA servers have been setup already. Every time we go to QA server to manually pull the lastest code with command line git pull command. Then run a web page to upgrade/downgrade database if database script has been updated.

Goal: Would use Azure DevOps to automate the process.

Here is what I would know:

- 1) With Azure DevOps, when deploying the code to QA server, could we only copy over the changed files? The software package is pretty big, it would take long time to copy the whole thing.
- 2) How Azure DevOps move files to QA server, does it use Git pull or file copy?
- 3) When using Azure DevOps tools, could we trigger a http(s) request?
- 4) Is there any tool I could check if Git repo has updates?
- 5) Is there any tool support if/else logic, because we would trigger the http(s) request only if Git repo has changes.

Just would get an overall idea.

Comment: Are you able to use another platform like jenkins instead Azure Devops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. as far as I know there is no layering\caching.
2. how would it use git pull to download from a web server? its using http request to download the package
3. not sure I understand the question, but you can have a script step in the deployment and do whatever you like (ie http(s) request)
4. this question doesnt make sense, you can use `git` command line, but I dont understand how that ties to the release process. you should build your code on commit and create a package that you would later consume in the release process
5. read 3 and 4.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.    For q1, not sure what is layering caching, I guess the answer is NO?  For q2, I guess I don't know how or where pipeline runs. If it is on cloud or locally? If it is on cloud, how it move big chunk of code to VM. In my case, all I need is a git pull.   For q4, we don't run it on commit, we run it daily. Thanks again.

Comment: 1. no layering\caching = full download required. 2. pipeline runs on the agent. it could be a cloud agent or your own vm. git pull is meaningless. it contains code, not packages\built application. 4. in that case it will run daily unless you create some script to check commits or something like that

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. For q2, since our application is Coldfusion application, we run on source code, so git pull is actually what we need. Taking in that do you know if it possible to run a git pull within the pipeline?

Comment: not natively, but you can always "hack" it. but this is not something you should do. you should create release packages and deploy those. that way you have some visibility.

Comment: Got it, Thanks! My brain is still in old Ant way, where Ant script sit on the web server and run the git pull.